# Evaluating an integral from 0 to 1 with a parameter, (and a dilogarithm)

Tags: calculus, integration, polylogarithm

So I need to evaluate the following integral (in terms of a):
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln{|1-\frac{y}{a}|}}{y} dy$$

Till now I have tried u-sub ($u = \ln{|1-\frac{y}{a}|}$, $u=\frac{y}{a}$) and integration by parts. Wolfram Alpha gives me the evaluation in terms of a dilogarithm ($-$Li$_2(\frac{y}{a}) + C$), but the problem with this solution is I don't know how to evaluate a dilogarithm. Any ideas on how one might evaluate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may not be a simplification in general since your definite integral is $-\textrm{Li}_2(\frac1a)$ when $a\ge 1$, and [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) usually does not have a simplification.

There will be special cases:

- when $a=1$ it is $-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$; this is also $\int_{0}^{a} \frac{\ln{|1-\frac{y}{a}|}}{y} dy$.
- when $a=2$ it is  $\frac12 (\log_e 2)^2 - \frac{\pi^2}{12}$
- when $a=\frac12$ it is  $-\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Comment: Hmm..Could you please explain how you got $\frac{-\pi^2}{6}$ for $a=1$?

Comment: @CeaealYT Lots of ways.  One is to take the series expansion of $\log(1-x)/x$ and integrate term by term to get $-\zeta(2)$

Comment: To expand on @Henry's comment. By plugging in $a=1$ into the series definition of the polylogarithm you get $-\mathrm{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1}\right) =- \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{k^2}$, and evaluating this series is the famous [Basel problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8337/695196) of which there are indeed many solutions. Notice that the value $a=1$ is special because $\left( \frac{1}{a}\right)^k = \left( \frac{1}{1}\right)^k = 1$ is a _constant_, but this isn't true for any other random number. This is an example of why these evaluations are special and can't be generalized.

Answer (score 0):

The dilogarithm is a special case of the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). It has the following series definition:
$$
\mathrm{Li}_{s}(z) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^k}{k^s}
$$
the dilogarithm is the special case of $s=2$. From here we can notice the following:
$$
\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\mathrm{Li}_{s}(t)}{t}\mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{z}\frac{1}{t}\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{t^k}{k^s}\mathrm{d}t = \sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k^s}\int_{0}^{z} t^{k-1}\mathrm{d}t =  \sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k^s}\frac{z^{k}}{k} =  \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^k}{k^{s+1}} = \mathrm{Li}_{s+1}(z)
$$
This gives us a recursive definition for the polylogarithms. Finally, recalling the geometric series formula [$\sum_{n\ge 0} t^n = \frac{1}{1-t}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) we get
$$
\mathrm{Li}_{1}(z) = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^k}{k} = \sum_{k\ge 1} \int_{0}^{z}t^{k-1}\mathrm{d}t= \int_{0}^{z}\sum_{k\ge 1} t^{k-1}\mathrm{d}t \overset{\color{purple}{n=k-1}}{=}  \int_{0}^{z}\sum_{n\ge \color{purple}{0}} t^{\color{purple}{n}}\mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{z}\frac{1}{1-t}\mathrm{d}t =-\ln(1-z)
$$
So combining this with the recursion proven before we get
$$
\mathrm{Li}_{2}(z) = \int_{0}^{z} \frac{\mathrm{Li}_{1}(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}u  = -\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\ln(1-u)}{u} \mathrm{d}u
$$
which is of the form of your integral after the $u$-sub $u = \frac{y}{a}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the dilogarithm function. But for some given a, is there a way to evaluate it **manually**?

Comment: What do you mean by "manually" exactly? Are you looking for a numerical approximation? If so, you can plug it into a [calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PolyLog%5B2%2C+1%2FPi%5D) to get a value. Otherwise, nice closed-form solutions only exist for specific special values of $a$, as pointed out in @Henry's answer.

Comment: Hmm...is it possible that if I understand how for specific values of a (like those in Henry's answers) have a nice closed-form solution, I can find a general method to evaluate it for others?

Comment: A general method doesn't exist. If there were, then there wouldn't be a need to have invented the digamma function in the first place since we could just write the result in terms of simpler functions. Your integral is an example of a [nonelementary integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral), which means it can be written in terms of elementary results. The specific values with nice form usually exploit some symmetry or special property that doesn't generalize to any other number.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x=\frac ya$, we have
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln{|1-\frac{y}{a}|}}{y} dy= \int_{0}^{\frac1a} \frac{\ln{|1-x|}}{x} dy $$
Using the expansion for $|x|<1$, $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k \\
\Leftrightarrow -\ln (1-x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k}
$$
Back to our integral, $$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) & =-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{a} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k-1}}{k} d x \\
& =-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\frac{1}{a}} \frac{x^{k-1}}{k} d x \\
& =-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^k}{k^2} \\
& =-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
For examples,
$$
I(1)=-\operatorname{Li}_2(1)=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=-\zeta(2)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
$$
I(2)=-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2 2^k}=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\ln ^2 2}{2}
$$